# Android class constructor not initiating, causing context null pointer exception?

Tags: android, constructor, nullpointerexception, android-context

I am currently writing a Class to export some data to CSV using a AsyncTask. I have written the class however when I call its constructor and pass in the context to be set I get a null pointer exception on the Context in the class. My CSV writer class is below:

```
public class ExportCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        Context mContext;

        public ExportCSVTask(Context context){
            Log.e("Error in MainActivity","Inside the Constructor");
            mContext = context;
        } 

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```

I have debugged the application and found that it does hit the "ExportCSVTask" with the correct context being passed, however it doesn't do anything any skips passed it. I created a Log message to test this and it appears that nothing inside the constructor is being executed and I don't know why. I have also put the code below which is what initiates the constructor:

```
try
                {
                    ExportCSVTask task = new ExportCSVTask(getApplicationContext());
                    task.execute("");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e("Error in MainActivity",ex.toString());
                }
```

I would really appreciate some help on this as I am stumped as to what could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is where you have this statement:

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```

That is a class level variable and the assignment runs before the constructor does. Hence at that point, mContext is null.

Just declare it without an assignment:

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog;
```

...and set it inside the constructor (after setting mContext):

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Member variables are initialized first and the constructor is called only then. So you dialog is initialized while `mContext` is still in its default `null` value.

Move the dialog initialization to constructor, or better yet, `onPreExecute()`.